# Sort list of class elements

Tags: c#, class-members

I have a record class like this :

```
public class RecordInfo
{
    public String CDate;
    public String Patient_ID;
    public Color Zone;
    public String Fname;
    public String Lname;
    public Int64 ImgSize;
    public String ImagePrefix;
    public String ImagePath;
    public String Sex;
    public String TZ;
}
```

and I made a list of RecordInfo like this :

```
List<RecordInfo> PatientRecords = new List<RecordInfo>();
```

and I added records to it, but I would like to sort that list based on Patient_ID, sex, Fname, etc.....

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) makes it easy using [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx), [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx), [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) and [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx):

```
// Note change from Patient_ID to PatientId for naming conventions.
List<RecordInfo> sorted = records.OrderBy(x => x.PatientId).ToList();
```

That will create a *new* list - LINQ is based on queries which project one sequence onto a new one, rather than mutating the existing list.

Alternatively, you could use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas) with a custom comparer to sort in-place.

Either way, I'd strongly recommend using properties instead of public fields, and also following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: What does the records refer to ?
Because i tried to replace it by PatientRecords but it didn`t work

Comment: @R.Vector, `it didn't work`? Could you translate `it didn't work` in English please? From a software developer perspective, not software user.

Comment: Yeah it says :The name 'records' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @R.Vector: Your original list of records. I didn't use the name `PatientRecords` as that isn't a good local variable name. As Darin suggests, "it didn't work" is not a clear description of what you're seeing.

Comment: @R.Vector: You said you replaced it with `PatientRecords` - it wouldn't have given that error afterwards...

Comment: Yeah after replacing it i got that error :

Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Slide_Sorter.RecordInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Slide_Sorter.RecordInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file to bring the namespace in which the `OrderBy` extension method is defined.